# Manipulating an iFrame from the parent window URL

Tags: facebook, url, iframe

So, I have an app in development. It's purpose is for people to upload drink recipes and to be able to view other people's uploaded drink recipes. Each drink recipe, when clicked on, fades in a mini-canvas box and makes the background fade dark. Each drink recipe has a "like" button within the now-visible drink recipe popup, and each of these drink recipes can be accessed through the URL. The drink is shared so that the shared link doesn't just lead to the page with all the recipes listed, but the actual shared recipe popup:

http://www.example.com/myapp.php?user_id=10009098039&dname=MyDrink

The `user_id` and `dname` will run through a function that displays the drink recipe popup.

Because the app is housed in my testing website and displayed through Facebook, which uses an iFrame to display it, a drink cannot be shared because the link will take the user back to where the app is housed. Is it possible to be able to manipulate the iFrame with the parent window's link?

Ex: https://facebook.com/pages/Test-Page/4080982098230923?sk=app_209302098302?user_id=10009098039&dname=MyDrink

or something of that nature.

Thank you. Please let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that when you click on a link in the iFrame the user is redirected to your page?

Comment: No. What happens is that the user can share the recipe by hitting the "like" button, and a post on his wall will appear with a link to the url that he "liked". That link is the link to the url of the app inside my website that houses that app, because fb wont house apps. I need that link to be the link to my page tab on facebook that has the iframe of the app, but i need the url of the facebook page tab window (parent to the app iframe) to force the drink recipe popup to appear, because that is what the user wants to share, the certain drink recipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use app_data and extract it from the signed_request. See: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462

Comment: Interesting... I will check that out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

not sure if this is what you are talking about, if not, forgive me!

Comment: Nah that's not what I need. You know how you can send data through the url ($_GET)? I need the parent window of the iframe to send a get request to the iframe basically. The parent window is my page on facebook, the iframe is my app on my housing site.

Comment: Not sure how to specify a target window through php. I did a little research and you may have to generate the html with the correct link via php, and use the target attribute